# How to deal with a figure that is really a table?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table already set as a PDF, and I need to include it, so the question is: how do I include it as a figure, but call it a table? I'd also like to move it from the list of figures to the list of tables.

Comment: lists of tables and captions like table: just come from the `table` environment, you can put anything in there, a tabular, an `\includegraphics` the text of war and peace in a small font...

Comment: You could use `\captionof{table}{your table caption}` and omit the table/figure/environment completely. Use `\usepackage{caption}` then

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that `\includegraphics` needs to be in a `figure` environment. It need not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common misunderstanding that `\includegraphics` needs to be in a figure environment. It need not, so you can certainly do

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{mytablefile.pdf}
    \caption{My table that I have as a PDF file}
    \label{tab:mytab}
\end{table}

As we see in Table~\ref{tab:mytab}, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics{pdfwithimageoftable}
\caption{my table\label{zzz}}
\end{table}
```